# Non-semisimple representations of the braid group in a semisimple braided category

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, braided-tensor-categories

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a semisimple braided tensor category (over $\mathbb{C}$, with finite dimensional hom spaces) and $X$ an object in $\mathcal{C}$.

Then for each n > 0 the braid group $B_n$ generates a subalgebra $A$ in $End(X^{\otimes n})$, making $End(X^{\otimes n})$ an $A$-module.

Is this module always completely reducible? Equivalently (I think), is the algebra $A$ always semisimple?

Comment: This is a very good question. Here is a very partial answer: If $\mathcal{C}$ is a group theoretical fusion category, then Etingof Rowell and Witherspoon (see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703274) proved that the action of the braid group splits via a finite quotient (see also https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4157 for more results in this direction). Since we are in characteristic zero, this means that this module is completely reducible. 
Notice that Naidu and Rowell also conjectured that their property F holds for all fusion categories which are weakly integral.